# How to make a field that is an entity as hidden in the form with SonataAdmin?

Tags: forms, symfony, sonata-admin

I need to add entity field as a hidden in my form
In the admin form with sonata I have:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {    
        if ($this->getRoot()->getSubject()->getId()) {
            $formMapper
                ->add('driverNight', 'hidden', array(), array('admin_code' => 'cab.admin.driver'))
            ->add('monday', 'checkbox', array('required' => false, "attr" => array('class' => 'checkbox-day'), 'label' => 'Monday', 'value' => '0'))
            ->add('tuesday', 'checkbox', array('required' => false, "attr" => array('class' => 'checkbox-day'), 'label' => 'Tuesday', 'value' => '0'))
            ->add('wednesday', 'checkbox', array('required' => false, "attr" => array('class' => 'checkbox-day'), 'label' => 'Wednesday', 'value' => '0'))
            ->add('thursday', 'checkbox', array('required' => false, "attr" => array('class' => 'checkbox-day'), 'label' => 'Thursday', 'value' => '0'))
            ->add('friday', 'checkbox', array('required' => false, "attr" => array('class' => 'checkbox-day'), 'label' => 'Friday', 'value' => '0'))
            ->add('saturday', 'checkbox', array('required' => false, "attr" => array('class' => 'checkbox-day'), 'label' => 'Saturday', 'value' => '0'))
            ->add('sunday', 'checkbox', array('required' => false, "attr" => array('class' => 'checkbox-day'), 'label' => 'Sunday', 'value' => '0'))

}
```

Actually, no value in the input (see the inspect image)

[image: inpect field in html]

How to make the driverNight field as hidden knowing that it is of type entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a data transformer as detailed here: [data transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html)

I suggest that you create a transformer class which transforms the `entity` to an `int` in the view layer and reverses from `int` to `entity` in the model layer and the use the `addModelTransformer` method in your config form.

1. Create the model Transformer class which implements `Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface` and contains 2 methods `transform` and `reverseTransform`. This class could be constructed by passing 2 arguments: Entity manager and the user entity object that will be transformed to int.

.

```
class DriverToIntTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface {
private $manager;
private $driver;

public function __construct(ObjectManager $manager, $oUser)
{
    $this->manager = $manager;
    $this->driver = $oUser;
}
public function transform($user)
{
    if (null === $user) {
        return $this->driver->getId();
    }
    return $user->getId();
}
public function reverseTransform($driverNumber)
{
    if (!$driverNumber) {
        return;
    }
    $oDriver = $this->manager
        ->getRepository('YourUserBundle:User')
        // query for the driver with this id
        ->find($driverNumber);
    if (null === $oDriver) {
        throw new TransformationFailedException(sprintf(
            'An user with number "%s" does not exist!',
            $driverNumber
        ));
    }
    return $oDriver;
}
```

2 call the transform method:

```
if ($this->getRoot()->getSubject()->getId()) {
        $driver = $this->getRoot()->getSubject()->getId(); 
$em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        $oDriver = $em->getRepository('YourUserBundle:User')->find($driver);
        $formMapper
            ->add('driverNight', 'hidden', array(), array('admin_code' => 'cab.admin.driver'));
        $formBuilder = $formMapper->getFormBuilder();
        $formBuilder->get('driverNight')->addModelTransformer(new DriverToIntTransformer($em, $oDriver));



    $formMapper
        ->add('monday', 'checkbox', array('required' => false, "attr" => array('class' => 'checkbox-day'), 'label' => 'Monday', 'value' => '0'));//.....
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I need.